# What could be the reason I cannot RDP to my Azure VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp

Two times I did create a new bare Windows Sever 2016 Azure VM. In both cases it is running (as the Azure dashboard shows me), but when I want to connect through RDP to the machine I get the standard message:

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons ...

Any tips on what could be reason and on how to fix it are very welcome.

Previously (until a couple of weeks ago) it always worked fine.

Comment: How do you create a new Azure VM? Do you enable the RDP port 3389 in your network security group? You can check the NSG setting from the virtual machine page--networking---INBOUND PORT RULES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any tips on what could be reason and on how to fix it are very
>   welcome.

RDP to windows based Azure VM can fail for various reasons. If you just create a new VM in Azure, probably it's a firewall restriction for the error. You can check if the RDP port 3389 be allowed from your client IP address in the network security group. If not, you can [add an inbound security rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic#create-security-rules) for that. You can verify the NSG set from the virtual machine page--networking---INBOUND PORT RULES. By default, the port 3389 is enabled in windows firewall for inbound traffic.

Also, you can verify that local network equipment such as routers and firewalls are not blocking outbound TCP port 3389, as noted in [Detailed troubleshooting steps for remote desktop connection issues to Windows VMs in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/detailed-troubleshoot-rdp).

Comment: Thanx, Nancy. Clear and I was just informed (having been away for a couple of weeks) that my company has blocked major outgoing ports, so that should be it. Have asked to get it solved.

Comment: Eventually, Nancy your suggestion was the solution. Indeed firewall rules were changed in our company but less strict that I was made to believe. Apparently MS has changed some things on deploying a new VM.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and glad this helps.:)